# Append html button to external component Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue2-dropzone

I'm using `vue-dropzone` component. And I want to add custom button on file preview. I take preview element by ref. And I can change styling or anything else. But when I add `<button>New Button</button>` then it came as string not an html button. How can I achieve this. You can reproduce from below codesandbox link.

[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-dropzone-demo-xp6w6)

How can I achieve this? If I can achieve this, then I will add onClick event that button.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-dropzone ref="myVueDropzone" id="dropzone" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import vue2Dropzone from "vue2-dropzone";
import "vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
  },
  mounted: function() {
    try {
      let mockFile = { name: "testfile.jpeg", size: 111 };
      this.$refs.myVueDropzone.manuallyAddFile(mockFile, "");
    } catch (err) {}

    const myElement = this.$refs.myVueDropzone.$el.querySelector(".dz-details");
    myElement.append("<button>New Button</button>");
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      dropzoneOptions: {
        url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        dictRemoveFile: "Remove"
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the button using javascript as below:

```
...
const myElement = this.$refs.myVueDropzone.$el.querySelector(".dz-details");
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML  = "New Button";
myElement.appendChild(button);
...
```